# Using jQuery append for a large list of select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using javascript to duplicate a couple select lists and append them to another element in the DOM.  One of these lists is very large: 29843 options.  I've read a lot of tips on improving the performance of jQuery's append method, including only appending once and using an array instead of concatenating.  I think the code below doesn't violate any of these practices, but when I call the append method, the browser (even Chrome) hangs.

```
var rows = $('.runRow');
var envOpts = rows[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML;  // contains 3 <option> tags
var sumOpts = rows[0].children[2].children[0].innerHTML;  // contains 29843 <option> tags

var newRow = "<span class=\"runRow\">";
newRow += "<span>Run " + (numRuns++) + "</span>";

newRow += "<span><select id=\"Environment" + numRuns + "\" name=\"Environment" + numRuns + "\">";
newRow += envOpts;
newRow += "</select></span>";

newRow += "<span><select id=\"SummaryID" + numRuns + "\" name=\"SummaryID" + numRuns + "\">";
newRow += sumOpts;
newRow += "</select></span>";

newRow += "</span>";

$('#RunsTable').append(newRow);
```

Am I asking too much of javascript, or is there a way to perform this operation?

Thanks!

Comment: Why in the world would you have a select box with nearly 30k choices?  How have your users not murdered you?

Comment: is rebuilding the selects actually faster then cloning them?

Comment: I agree.  You might have a use case that can be solved with an entirely different approach.  Describe your use case and you might get some good advice.

Comment: Actually, now that I reread this, it looks like he is trying to pull the options OUT of the options list and just show them in the DOM. Not create a giant list. Which actually makes sense.

Comment: Quick test: it took my browser (Safari) approx. 3 seconds to create and append 30,000 options - but it then needs about 5 seconds to open the select menu when you click on it. Even if you could speed up the creation, you still won't be able to improve performance for showing the menu...

Comment: I'm migrating an old app from classic ASP to ASP.NET MVC. I have limited authority to make changes to the existing app.  The old app handles this by doing a full page refresh, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: However, you do can gain some performance by not using jQuery's `append` but instead creating a single wrapper DOM element (e.g. a div), setting it's `innerHTML` to your content and then explicitly attaching the wrapper to the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking too much.  Not necessarily of jQuery, though, or even JavaScript.  As James Montagne's comment suggests, your (ab)use of the idea of a dropdown menu might be outide the bounds of what the operating system/windowing framework performs well with.

Have you considered a hierarchical approach, with the 30k options categorized and then presented to the user as a list of dropdowns?

Comment: Thanks, from the discussion it sounds like a redesign is in order.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is a means that is faster than what you are currently trying, but still pretty slow. This actually uses javascript to both create and display the 30k options so we are really working the system here. It takes about sixty seconds to render on my two year old laptop. You start by using `array.push` and `join` which offer significant performance improvements over `+= string`.

http://jsfiddle.net/yuTtK/1/  - Link defaults to 300 as not to swamp someone's browser.

```
//create an option list with 30k options
var options = [];
for (var i = 0; i< 30000; i++) {
    options.push('<option>'+i+'</option>');
}
$('select').append(options.join(''));

//copy each select list item onto the page
var myArray = [];
var list = $('option');
for (var j=0; j < list.length; j++) {
    myArray.push('<span>'+list[j].innerHTML+'</span><br/>');
}
$('body').append(myArray.join(''));
```

To make this more user friendly you can use a timeout and a loading message so that the browser is responsive while it iterates over the list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to divide options into groups and having them depending one from the others if possible. But why the hell you need 28000(!) options???

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Paul and Dan on this one.  Another option which I particularly like implementing for huge lists is autocomplete.  Making an ajax call to grab the top ten or so choices based on keystrokes is a lot more efficient than trying to pull in 30K.